# Is popular name for Brompton bike written as "Bromie", "Brommie" or "Bromi"?

Tags: word-choice, british-english

Owners of Brompton bikes often call their bikes as [bromi] bikes. I am wondering what is written version of this word. On the internet I can find all three versions. What do you find best one if I want for instance to register domain name with this word. Thank you for answer.

Comment: I would say that the majority of English speakers don't know what a Brompton is.

Comment: @HotLicks - Harsh, but probably fair. I suspect that if we limited it to people in big cities in England we might just about manage a majority.

Comment: Note that for a domain name it's probably better to have a slightly quirky term.

Answer (score 1):

As a former Brompton rider - er, what? I called it a Brompton. But googling suggests you're not incorrect that some people abbreviate it.

---

From the point of view of English, in order to maintain the vowel sound of the "o", your abbreviation should have a double "m". It could end "-ie" or "y".

Doing a [custom google search on www.myorangebrompton.com](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=cQo6W6HeA4TYgAao1I7QCA&q=site%3Amyorangebrompton.com%20brommie&oq=site%3Amyorangebrompton.com%20brommie&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10759.11288.0.11638.3.3.0.0.0.0.41.118.3.3.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.rSgXgfGXw1o) (as far as I know the most popular blog about bromptons) yields 47 hits for "brommie". I got 1 hit each for "bromie" and "brommy". No hits for "bromi" or "bromy".

A google search for "[brommie folding bike](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&q=brommie%20folding%20bike&nirf=brompton%20folding%20bike&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQ6MH9p4DcAhWrD8AKHaetBTQQ8BYIJSgB&biw=767&bih=740)" found plenty of hits (25,500). Not all of the pages' synopses have the word "brommie" but plenty do. A similar search for "[brommy folding bike](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&q=%22brommy%22%20folding%20bike&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjE1ZGwqIDcAhVCDMAKHQvnDWoQ5t4CCDwwBg&biw=767&bih=740)" yields 6200; "[bromie](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22bromie%22%20folding%20bike&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&ei=CA06W5rEHofygQbN9I2gBw&start=90&sa=N&biw=767&bih=740) folding bike" gives 3800; and "[bromy folding bike](https://www.google.co.uk/search?sa=X&rlz=1C1EJFA_enGB778GB778&nirf=brompton%20folding%20bike&q=%22bromy%22%20folding%20bike&ved=0ahUKEwjL1viMqYDcAhWkF8AKHfH9BQAQ5t4CCCwwAA&biw=767&bih=740)" gives less than 300, but the synopses don't look like they're using "bromy" as an abbreviation for brompton.

---

In conclusion, I'd recommend **"brommie"** for both working with English's usual pronunciation guidelines and being in (relatively) common usage already.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are more interested in the most commonly searched rather than the best word. There are tools to do this - https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=GB&q=brommie,bromie,bromi - it looks like bromi takes it.

Comment: How many of those results are for brompton bikes, and how many for other things?